# Which is the best way in this case to extract the substring from a string which is inputted by the user in C

Tags: c, string

Let's say I have the following string stored in char *m;

```
char *m = "K: someword\r\n";
```

The **m** will be inputed by the user so the user will write in the console:

```
K: someword\r\n
```

The **someword** can have different length, while **K:    \r\n** will always be the same.
Now my question is, which is the best way after I read this input to extract **someword** from it and save it into a new char* variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char buffer [50], k, return_car, new_line;

  int n = sscanf ("K: someword\r\n", "%c: %s%c%c", &k, buffer, &return_car, &new_line);
  printf ("The word is \"%s\". sscanf() read %d items.\n", buffer, n);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> The word is "someword". sscanf() read 4 items

Answer (score 0):

Since both the substrings we aren't interested in (`"K: "` and `"\r\n"`) are of fixed length, you can do this:

```
char *s;
size_t len = strlen(m);
s = malloc(len);
strcpy(s, m + 3);
s[len - 4] = 0;
printf("%s\n", s);
free(s);
```

Note that I declared a new `char *` variable to copy to since `m` is in read-only memory, and that robust code would handle the case where `malloc` failed and returned `NULL`.

Comment: Why do we move [len - 4], '\n' '\r' are count as 1 character, right?

Comment: @Dan No, they are separate characters, also remember that `len` is the length of  the original string in `m`, not `s` (which is already 3 characters shorter)

Comment: If I want to change the m itself from "K: someword\r\n" to just "someword" whithout using any helper variable, how should I do it ?

Comment: You can't since it was declared with type `char *`; that's read-only memory

Comment: Okay, buy the "K: someword\r\n" is to be inputted by the user, should I go s[len - 6] since the user will also press enter to send. Btw my implementation is a loop so the user will always write something new, I tried to implement your code and it works on the first iteration like the s is "someword" but in the next itereation when the user inputs "K: anotherword\r\n" the s becomes ": anotherwor". Can you tell me how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *m = "K: someword\r\n";
    const size_t someword_len = strlen(&m[3]);
    char *someword = malloc(someword_len);
    if (someword == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Malloc error\n"); abort(); }
    memcpy(someword, &m[3], someword_len - 2);
    someword[someword_len - 1] = '\0';

    puts(someword);

    free(someword);
}
```

1. You assume that string `m` **always** starts with `"K: "` (that's 3 characters) and ends with `"\r\n"` (that's two characters).
2. I believe `strlen(m)` will be faster then `strchr(m, '\r')` or `strrchr(m, '\r')` on most platforms
3. After you have the length of the string, using `memcpy` instead of `strcpy` will be faster.
4. Remember to null terminate your string
5. Remember to handle errors.

Comment: Your code gives me the output `somewordi`, not `someword` as expected

Comment: @GovindParmar Tested it at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk84_3nT7). Outputs `someword` there.  : /